# Asymptotic rendering time for koch snowflakes

Tags: asymptotics, fractals

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534115/koch-snowflake-rendering-time-and-how-to-draw-a-snowflake-using-turtle) on stack-overflow, but this may be a more proper forum since it is more math-related than programming related:

I'm currently working through the online course material for the MIT 6.006 course for fun. I'm on problem set #2 ([found here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/)) and had a question about the calculations for the asymptotic rendering time for the koch snowflake problem (problem #1).

According to the solutions, when the CPU is responsible for the rendering and the calculation of coordinates, the asymptotic rendering time is faster than if the process is split up between the CPU and GPU. The math makes sense to me, but does anyone have an intuition about why this is true?

In my mind, the CPU still has to calculate the coordinates to render the snowflake ($\Theta( 4^n)$ time), and then has to render the image. In my mind, these should be additive, not multiplicative.

However, the solutions state these are multiplicative, so since each triangle/line segment is shorter (for the last two subproblems in problem 1) the runtime is reduced to either $\Theta\left(\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n\right)$ or $\Theta(1)$.

I'm not a computer scientist--this stuff is just a fun hobby for me. I'd really appreciate an answer from one of you geniuses out there :)

Comment: The point is, the CPU must wait for the GPU to finish its task; and if the GPU is slower, the CPU ends up wasting cycles.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. It still seems to me that even if all processes are handled by the CPU, it will still have to calculate the coordinates and then render the object. So it seems to me like these should be additive, not multiplicative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the comments on P.5 of the problem set, the approach taken by the CPU and the GPU are different.

The CPU-only (without hardware acceleration) appproach is to first compute what needs to be drawn, and then send it to the GPU to draw. Since we are assuming that the cost to rasterize is bigger than the cost to gather the line segments, then the amount of time to draw the image will be dominated by the GPU, whose cost will be proportional to the number of pixels it actually has to draw.

The GPU-CPU (with hardware acceleration) approach computes all the triangles, big and small, and then sends them to the GPU to draw the big triangle, delete the middle pixels, draw the smaller triangles, delete the unneeded pixels, and so on. Since drawing takes a long time, then the time GPU has to spend drawing and erasing will dominate the total amount of time spent; since most (asymptotically, 100%) of the pixels that are drawn will in the end be erased, then the total amount of time taken will be substantially more than simply the number of pixels that actually have to be drawn.

In other words: the hardware-acceleration scenario dumps most of the work on to the GPU, which is much slower than the CPU. This is okay if the CPU has other things to work on while the GPU is doing its processing; however, this is not the case here; so, the CPU is just wasting cycles while the GPU is doing its drawing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I'm beginning to understand. Do you have any idea why it's called "hardware _acceleration_" then? It seems like it slows things down.

Comment: Well, the point is, if "rendering snowflakes" is not your only task behind a computer, then the CPU can work on other things while the GPU is rendering the snowflake.  So the number of cycles on the CPU will be decreased; however, the total time for the snowflake will be bigger.
p.s., please accept my answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Still, it seems ridiculous that the calculation is constant time to create the same image that takes exponential time with GPU rendering! It just doesn't make any sort of sense in my mind. I'm going to leave it open just in case someone else has an explanation that can penetrate my thick skull. I really appreciate your help, though!

Comment: Alright, I will try one last time. If we are NOT using GPU rendering, then all the GPU has to do is to draw the shape that the CPU gives it (since we are assuming the CPU calculations are much quicker). If we ARE using GPU rendering, then the GPU has to do all the drawing and erasing; and since the GPU takes much longer than the CPU, then this drawing and erasing takes much longer than just drawing in the first scenario. p.s., I updated the last 2 paragraphs; see if it's good enough at least to upvote...

Comment: Okay--I think I get it. Basically, just everything you've been saying. To the CPU, using 'hardware speedup', each triangle cost is the same, independent of how large that triangle is. When the CPU has to actually figure out how to rasterize the object, the calculation is reduced in time proportional to the size of the triangle. Therefore, as the LoD becomes larger, the triangles become smaller and time will not increase beyond a constant factor.

Comment: Thanks for the rep.  To me, your explanation sounds as convolutedly worded as mine probably did to you; however, this difference is probably due to the fact that you are a computer scientist, and I am a mathematician...

Comment: Yeah, that was a bad way to explain it. Maybe this is a better way: The problem states that when the CPU sends information to the GPU, the rendering time of each triangle is equivalent. However, when the CPU takes care of the calculation by itself, the rendering time is reduced in proportion to the size of the triangle. Therefore, the entire computation is massively reduced in time because it changes a constant factor to an exponentially decreasing function of n. Thanks again, you rock.